# Network connection error - unreachable with one user

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager

I have a desktop with Ubuntu 20.04 and it has the following problem. When I try to connect to the wired network it works with one user and with another, despite connecting, if I try to access the internet it tells me network unreachable. I looked and the firewall is disabled. Both users access the network using DHCP. Any idea what it could be?